# How do I copy to clipboard using clipboardy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clipboard

I am trying to use clipboard in order to copy 'longlat' to the clipboard by passing it through the function 'copyData()'. However, it keeps giving me errors.

This is the error (1. Clipboardy.writeSync not a function and 2.UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning) :

```
(node:16596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: clipboardy.writeSync is not a function
    at copyData (C:\Users\Nicky\index.js:46:14)
    at C:\Users\Nicky\index.js:32:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:16596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16596) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my code

```
  const clipboardy = (...args) => import('clipboardy').then(({default: clipboardy}) => clipboardy(...args));
  const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
 
  const url = "https://www.google.com/";
  
  async function StartScraping() {
    await puppeteer
      .launch({
        headless: false,
      })
      .then(async (browser) => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
  
        await page.setViewport({
          width: 2000,
          height: 800,
        });
  
        page.on("response", async (response) => {
  
         
          if (response.url().includes("General")) {
            const location = await response.text() 
            let intlong = location.indexOf("Example:")
            const longlat = location.substring(intlong, intlong + 46)
           
            console.log(longlat);



            copyData(longlat)
            
            }
  
        });
  
        await page.goto(url, {
          waitUntil: "load",
          timeout: 0,
        });
      });
  }

function copyData(data1) {
  clipboardy.writeSync(data1)
}



  StartScraping();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
    .invoke('readText').then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

Should do the trick. If you are using cypress on the browser

Comment: The OP clearly is not using cypress. This also doesn't use clipboardy.